# how to implement Factory Initializer with factory creator

Tags: c#, initialization, factory, factory-pattern

i use this factory creator method to instantiate a class on my project...
but i have to put every single parameter to pass into it to be initialized,
for example if i have to pass ten arguments there is some way to make it better?

```
using System.Collections;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MyClass 
{

```
float myFloat ;
int     myInt;
object[] myObjects;

public static MyClass Create(
    float           in_somefloat,
    int             in_someInt,
    object[]        someObject
)
{
    MyClass instance = new MyClass();

    if(instance != null)
    {
        if(instance.Initialize(
            in_somefloat,
            in_someInt,
            someObject
        ))
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

private bool Initialize(
    float           in_somefloat,
    int             in_someInt,
    object[]        someObject   
)
{

    myFloat = in_somefloat;
    myInt = in_someInt;
    myObjects = someObject;

    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: There is not even one argument, how can we see the problem you talking about ? Yes, if the constructor has arguments, you have to pass the arguments.

Comment: Please refactor the question. Also if you want a code review, please ask here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: edited, as you can see if i want to  pass other argument my factory function will be too long, any advice to make it looks better?